# Has there been research on the effects of the Presidential Records Act on White House decision making?

Tags: united-states, president, political-research

The [Presidential Records Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_Records_Act) mandates the preservation of all presidential records. At least in theory this means that the only Presidential communications immune from further scrutiny are phone calls ([which are not recorded](https://wtop.com/j-j-green-national/2019/11/anatomy-of-a-presidential-phone-call/)) and verbal in-person conversations. Presumably this might create a bit of a bias against written communication, as there's plenty of discussions that the White House might not want to be exposed in the future.

Has there been any academic research on the effects of this Act on communications within the White House since 1971?

Comment: You can find the legal definition of presidential materials/records here - https://www.archives.gov/about/laws/presidential-records.html, then narrow down your question to be more focused.

Comment: Even though the White House doesn't record POTUS's phone calls, they can be recorded by others. That's how we all heard Trump's call to Brad Raffensperger where he asked him to "find 11,780 votes". Is this subject to the PRA?

Comment: @Barmar yes and it gives an incentive to *not* make any records whatsoever

Comment: @r13 question seems pretty focussed and looking up the definition of PRA doesn't enlighten us all that much on whether POTUSs have adapted to it by privileging communication channels that are off the record for PRA.  I was wondering if similar studies had been carried out on how companies communicate internally given how often smoking guns are found during email discovery.  But didn't see anything beyond a whole lot of provider solutions to perform that discovery.  Still, it seems to me that "Don't recall those Pintos" or "Cheat that NO2 test" comms would be kept verbal nowadays.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica You seem to have a good grab on the question the OP focused on, why not write something about it to lighten others?

Comment: I understand what the question is about - if you are up to questionable practices, you may want to not leave traces of doing so.  I **don't** know the answer however.  However, I wonder know if a study would be all that enlightening - of only 6-7 POTUS since Nixon, desire to "bury things" would vary widely between "Mr. Ethics" Carter and well, Trump.

Comment: The office of the national archive should work like a library with the signed records on all check-ins and check-outs. Before leaving the White House, don't they check what items the president owes to the library, especially highly sensitive documents? Whose practice is questionable?

Comment: How would you even perform such a study? How would we know what kinds of records the pre-PRA presidents were keeping, so we could compare them to the records of post-PRE presidents? Also, technology has changed drastically -- there was no Internet when the PRA was passed, so no Twitter. So how would you determine whether changes were related to the PRA or tech?

Comment: @Barmar surveys maybe?

Comment: Who would you survey? Carter is the only living pre-PRA POTUS.

Comment: @Barmar presumably such research could've happened back in the 80s and 90s

Comment: @JonathanReez Then there wouldn't have been enough post-PRA Presidents to compare. In general, this seems like something too specialized to get a decent survey. There have only been a handful of Presidents since then, and they're so different from each other that you could hardly attribute any changes in their behavior to a specific act. Unless someone can remember a POTUS telling them "let's do this by phone so it won't be archived".

Comment: And note that even though they were phone calls, we have a recording of Trump's call to Raffensberger, and we have detailed recollections of the infamous Ukraine call.

Comment: @Barmar Trump famously used his personal cell phone to entirely avoid the chance of his aides making any notes. I imagine other Presidents might've used other tricks - i.e. plain out ordering aides to not take notes when they're meeting certain people.

Comment: @JonathanReez Exactly my point about technology. That's an option not available to pre-PRA presidents, so we don't know whether or not they would have done the same thing despite the lack of PRA.